# Region bounded by $y= x$, $x=0$ and $y=15$, rotated about the x-axis and y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am wondering if there is a difference between the answers of these when getting the volume of solid of revolution:

Region bounded by $y = x$, $x = 0$ and $y = 15$, rotated about the $x-axis$

Region bounded by $y = x$, $x = 0$ and $y = 15$, rotated about the $y-axis$

I tried the first one which is rotated about the x-axis and I got $2250π$.

For the second one I am confused on how to solve, is it possible that I use any of disk, washer, or shell method?

Comment: What did you get? What is $2250\pi$? Is it volume?

Comment: @VIVID Sorry, I forgot to indicate it. Yes, volume :)

Comment: When you rotate around y-axis, you get a cone with height $h = 15$ and radius $r = 15$ so the volume will be $1125 \pi$. When you rotate around x-axis, it is the cone of same volume cut out from a cylinder of height $h = 15$ and radius $15$. So you get $2250 \pi$.

Comment: @VIVID  Thank you, can I use any of the methods, disk, washer, or shell?

Comment: Can you describe those methods? I agree with @MathLover and so does my answer. Try this!

Comment: @SwaytheDestroyer'STD' Whatever method you use will get the same answer. Although usually we just pick whichever one is the easiest to integrate. In this case, it looks like disc (i.e. washer, just the same name) method is the easiest.

Although the *really* easy one is to simply not use calculus.

Answer (score 1):

No objects are not the same.

- Your region is the following triangle:

> [image]

---

- Rotation around the $x$-axis:

> [image]

---

- Rotation around the $y$-axis:

> [image]

---

However, you should be able to see the **relation between their volumes**.

Answer (score 1):

Volume of the figure produced by rotation is equal to $V = 2 *S * π * r$

Where S is area of cross-section, r is distance of the center of mass from rotation axis.

For x it is 10, for y it is 5, see pic.

So we get for the first case $2 *1/2 * 15^2 * 10 = 2250 π$
In second case $2 *1/2 * 15^2 * 5 = 1125 π$

plot of the area

[image]